# Unable to login into meta.stats.stackexchange.com using my openid

Tags: support, area-51

I am logged into the stats.stackexchange.com but not on meta.stats.stackexchange.com. When I click login on meta I am prompted to choose my openid. Upon clicking the openid I see this message:

"You are currently logged in.

Do you want to log out and log in as this OpenID?"

When I click on "log in" I am redirected to the meta page but the page indicates that I am still not logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear your cookies and try again.